# In which file in WordPress do I change the "Add to cart" and quantity buttons' aspect? + quantity counter

Tags: php, wordpress

In which file can I change the form.cart section? Ex, I don't want the "Add to cart" button to be on the same lime as the quantity buttons - and how can I do this?

I would also want to add a third section which will calculate the total price automatically depending on the quantity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get the code of single product from the file path: 
**wp-content/plugins/woocommerce/templates/single-product/add-to-cart/simple.php**

But you want to add third section on product detail single page for calculate the total price automatically depending on the quantity as mentioned in your comments.

Then, you can paste the custom code on function.php file,

Try this code,

```html
add_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'woocommerce_total_product_price', 31 );
function woocommerce_total_product_price() {
    global $woocommerce, $product;
    // let's setup our divs
    echo sprintf('<div id="product_total_price" style="margin-bottom:20px;">%s %s</div>',__('Product Total:','woocommerce'),'<span class="price">'.$product->get_price().'</span>');
    ?>
        <script>
            jQuery(function($){
                var price = <?php echo $product->get_price(); ?>,
                    currency = '<?php echo get_woocommerce_currency_symbol(); ?>';

                $('[name=quantity]').change(function(){
                    if (!(this.value < 1)) {

                        var product_total = parseFloat(price * this.value);

                        $('#product_total_price .price').html( currency + product_total.toFixed(2));

                    }
                });
            });
        </script>
    <?php
}
```

**source:** http://reigelgallarde.me/programming/show-product-price-times-selected-quantity-on-woocommecre-product-page/

[image]

Comment: Works perfectly. Thanks a lot!!

Comment: Do you happen to know hot to put the cart button on o separate row? I don't want it near the counter

Comment: Then, you can set the design by css.

Comment: and in which file do I change the CSS for that?